# Gerar uma Generic String com dados de duas tabelas - Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

estou com um pequeno problema.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para aprendizado, mas um dos requisitos que eu mesmo "inventei" é o de gerar uma string base. Vou tentar detalhar.

```
Tenho a tabela **term** com os seguintes campos:
term_id
term

Tenho a tabela **synonymous** com os seguintes campos:  
synonymous_id
term_id
synonymous
```

**A ideia é que eu consiga imprimir algo nesse modelo:**

```
"$term1" OR "synonymous1" OR "synonymous2" AND "$term2" OR "synonymous3" OR "synonymous3".
```

Não sei se ficou claro. Mas basicamente eu vou poder ter vários sinônimos para um termo, isso acarretaria em vários OR's. Assim como posso ter vários TERMOS, o que acarretaria em vários AND's. Um SINÔNIMO só existe se estiver atrelado a um TERMO. Um TERMO não precisa obrigatoriamente ter um SINÔNIMO.

Alguma sugestão de que caminho eu devo começar para produzir esse algoritmo? Queria adicionar ao meu projeto que é basicamente em php com arranhões de JS.

Grato dese já!

Comment: Você quer listar todos os termos e seus sinônimos, caso existam? Se for isso, você resolve com um left join.